How to Invert Colors Using Preview in Mac OS 15?
I used to invert colors on an image using the Mac OS Preview app as described, for example, here or here using "Tools > Adjust Color window, then switching the position of the Black point and White point sliders in the Adjust Colors panel"
But in Mac OS 15 this is no longer working for me. The Preview App will no longer allow me to move the Black point slider past the White point slider, as shown in this screen recording:


@SolarMike did what you suggest work for you? When I tried  that the result was terrible -- not inverted and totally pixelated because so much info was lost.

Wonder what happened to my last comment?

Apparently this is a bug in Mac OS 15.0 and will be fixed in in the next update.

Yes, in 15.1 Beta, this has been fixed
